# Internet not searching location in flutter

Tags: flutter

I copied code from a tutorial and the app is not working properly in the real device, only in the emulator.
Here's part of the code that shows the problem, don't know if i'm doing something wrong.

```
void onSearchBarTextChanged(String value) async {
if (await connectionStatus.checkConnection()) {
  isSnackbarOn = false;
  if (value == '') {
    typingState = false;
    loadingState = false;
  } else {
    loadingState = true;
    typingState = true;
    update();
    locationList = ((await api.getCities(value))
        .toList()
        .map((city) => Location.fromAPI(city))).toList();
    loadingState = false;
  }
  update();
} else {
  searchTextConroller.clear();
  if (!isSnackbarOn) {
    showSnackBar(
        title: "Connection", description: "No internet connection");
  }
}
```

}

And the textinput is this:

```
Container(
          child: controller.components.buildAppbar(
              node: controller.focusNode,
              onLocationIconClicked: () => controller.getLocationFromGps(),
              onTextChanged: (value) =>
                  controller.onSearchBarTextChanged(value),
              offset: controller.scrollOffset,
              controller: controller,
              onClickBack: () => controller.backClicked()),
        ),
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? If there's an error, can you include that information as well in the question? "Not working properly" isn't that clear and makes it hard for us to help

Comment: Just show the snackbar on the phone, in the emulator works fine...so i don't know the error

Comment: is the URL for API http or https?  And if the former, did you give special permission to contact http URLs from the device?  That's not the default any more.

Comment: Oh, now its working... i don't know about the permission that we have to give, I add in the androidmanifest and it's fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just added the permission in the AndroidManifest and worked.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```